# Referencing JSON elements in AppleScript

Tags: json, applescript

I have a JSON result I am trying to work with in AppleScript, but because the top level items are "unnamed" I can only access them by piping the item reference, which in this case is a number. As a result, I can't iterate through it, it has to be hard coded (scroll down to the last code sample to see what I mean)

For example, this is the JSON I'm looking at:

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "Tri 1"
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "Tri 2"
    },
    "3": {
        "name": "Tri 3"
    },
    "4": {
        "name": "Orb Dave"
    },
    "5": {
        "name": "Orb Fah"
    }
}
```

With the help of JSON Helper I get the JSON to a more usable format (for AppleScript).

```
{|3|:{|name|:"Tri 3"}, |1|:{|name|:"Tri 1"}, |4|:{|name|:"Orb Dave"}, |2|:{|name|:"Tri 2"}, |5|:{|name|:"Orb Fah"}}
```

I can then use this code to get a list of "lights" the objects in question:

```
set lights to (every item in theReturn) as list
repeat with n from 1 to count of lights
    set light to item n of lights
    log n & light
end repeat
```

From that, I get:

```
(*1, Tri 3*)
(*2, Tri 1*)
(*3, Orb Dave*)
(*4, Tri 2*)
(*5, Orb Fah*)
```

You may notice the result is not in the desired order. The index is the index within the list of lights. It's not the number that appears at the top of the object. If you look to the top two pre-formated areas, you'll see the items 1,2 and 3 are Tri 1, Tri 2, and Tri 3. It is correct that Tri 3 comes first, Tri 1 second, and an Orb is third.

What I need to do is find a way to be able to iterate through the JSON in any order (sorted or not) and be able to line up "1" with "Tri 1", "3" with "Tri 3" and "5" with "Orb Fah". But I can't find ANY way to interact with the returned JSON that lets me reference the third light and return it's name. The ONLY way I can seem to be able to do it is to hard code the light indexes, such that:

```
log |name| of |1| of theReturn
log |name| of |2| of theReturn
log |name| of |3| of theReturn
log |name| of |4| of theReturn
log |name| of |5| of theReturn
```

which gives me the correct light with the correct name:

```
(*Tri 1*)
(*Tri 2*)
(*Tri 3*)
(*Orb Dave*)
(*Orb Fah*)
```

I'm thinking the problem is arising because the light ID doesn't have a descriptor or sorts. That I can't change, but I need to iterate through them programatically. Hard coding them as above is not acceptable.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with a list of records here, not a list of lists. Records are key/value pairs. They do not have indexes like a list. That makes it easy if you know the keys because you just ask for the one you want. And your records have records inside them so you have 2 layers of records. Therefore if you want the value of the |name| record corresponding to |3| record then ask for it as you've discovered...

```
set jsonRecord to {|3|:{|name|:"Tri 3"}, |1|:{|name|:"Tri 1"}, |4|:{|name|:"Orb Dave"}, |2|:{|name|:"Tri 2"}, |5|:{|name|:"Orb Fah"}}
set record3name to |name| of |3| of jsonRecord
```

The downside of records in applescript is that there is no command to find the record keys. Other programming languages give you the tools to find the keys (like objective-c) but applescript does not. You have to know them ahead of time and use them as I showed.

If you don't know the keys ahead of time then you can either use JSON Helper to give you the results in a different form or use a different programming language (python, ruby, etc) to extract the information from the records.

One other option you have is to just use the json text itself without using JSON Helper. For example, if you have the json as text then you can extract the information using standard applescript commands for text objects. Your json text has the information you want on the 3rd line, the 6th, 9th etc. You could use that to your advantage and do something like this...

```
set jsonText to "{
    \"1\": {
        \"name\": \"Tri 1\"
    },
    \"2\": {
        \"name\": \"Tri 2\"
    },
    \"3\": {
        \"name\": \"Tri 3\"
    },
    \"4\": {
        \"name\": \"Orb Dave\"
    },
    \"5\": {
        \"name\": \"Orb Fah\"
    }
}"

set jsonList to paragraphs of jsonText

set namesList to {}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ": \""
repeat with i from 3 to count of jsonList by 3
    set theseItems to text items of (item i of jsonList)
    set end of namesList to text 1 through -2 of (item 2 of theseItems)
end repeat
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""

return namesList
```

Comment: I thank you for your time in answering this, I had a strong feeling I was hitting an AppleScript limitation. In the end I'll be making a web service to deal with this, so it might be time to move onto that now and do it in php or python (I've been meaning to learn python anyway).

Comment: The problem with the latter approach is that this is only one type of return (and an easier one). The name is purely for the users reference, the actual reference I need to use (programmatically) is 1, 2, 3, etc. I can assume they are in order and incremental, but (although unlikely) it is possible that there is no third record and the list could be 1, 2, 4, and 5. At the end of the day, they are the important pieces of info I want to reference. Having said that, I can work with the approach you've outlined at the end there. I'll revisit it and have a think about the best way to approach it.

Comment: "Records are key/value pairs." They're not; they're collections of properties, i.e. identifier-value bindings, roughly analogous to C structs. They're not intended to represent arbitrary collections whose keys are values; for that, you want a map/hash/dictionary/associative array, but AS lacks such a type.  If you're on 10.7+, you could work around it by basing your script on the Cocoa-AppleScript Applet template. That'll let you use NSJSONSerialization to unpack your JSON as an NSDictionary which you can then manipulate as you want. Or yeah, just learn Python instead.

Answer (score 2):

For each index, loop through all the items in the list looking for the one whose name matches the index:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    -- Convert the JSON file to a property list using plutil.
    do shell script "plutil -convert xml1 /Users/mxn/Desktop/tri.json -o /Users/mxn/Desktop/tri.plist"
    -- Read in the plist
    set theItems to every property list item of property list file "/Users/mxn/Desktop/tri.plist"
    set theLights to {}
    -- Iterate once per item in the plist.
    repeat with i from 1 to count of theItems
        set theName to i as text
        -- Find the item whose name is the current index.
        repeat with theItem in theItems
            if theItem's name is theName then
                -- We found it, so add it to the results.
                set theValue to theItem's value
                copy {i, theValue's |name|} to the end of theLights
                -- Move on to the next index.
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
    return theLights
end tell
```

Result:

```applescript
{{1, "Tri 1"}, {2, "Tri 2"}, {3, "Tri 3"}, {4, "Orb Dave"}, {5, "Orb Fah"}}
```

Ideally, instead of the nested loop, we’d be able to say something like this:

```applescript
set theName to i as text
set theItem to (the first item in theItems whose name is theName)
```

But unfortunately that produces an error.

---

This solution also demonstrates an alternative to JSON Helper: you can convert the JSON file to a property list using the handy `plutil` command line tool and use System Events' built-in support for property lists.